# Equivalent expressions for quotient set $(\mathbb{Z},+)/(m\mathbb{Z},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617948/360485) answer I tried to write down the quotient set $(\mathbb{Z},+)/(m \mathbb{Z},+)$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now If I got it right, it should be
$$ \{  m\mathbb{Z}+0, m\mathbb{Z}+1,m\mathbb{Z}+2,...,m\mathbb{Z}+(m-1) \} $$

I was told that this was equivalent to
$$ [0],[1],[2],...,[m-1] $$
where the braces $[...]$ indicate an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

Is there a way I can immediately recognize that this is in fact the case?
Is this comparable to a quotient space where this would imply that *e.g.* $m\mathbb{Z}+1\sim 1$ because these elements only differ by an element of the sub-group $(m\mathbb{Z},+)$, *i.e.*, by the element $m\mathbb{Z}$

Or is my assumption wrong in the first place?

(Sorry for my inaccurate syntax...Im nowhere near to be a mathematician)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can immediately recognize that this is in fact the case?

Yes, by definition of $[a]_m$:

$$\begin{align}
[a]_m&=\{a+M\mid M\in m\Bbb Z\} \\
&=\{ a+mx\mid x\in \Bbb Z\},
\end{align}$$ so $[a]_m=[b]_m$ iff $m\mid (a-b)$, leading to a complete system of residues modulo $m$.